# Recover Hangouts data using Android File Transfer

Tags: sms, backup, file-transfer

My [nexus 5](http://drop.ndtv.com/TECH/product_database/images/1112013121149AM_635_google_nexus_5.jpeg)'s screen just went black :( ... In the past days I noticed a bit of flickering and was planning to do a full phone backup, but didn't get to it on time.

Luckily, I removed the passcode (just in case) and that allowed me to connect the phone to my mac and back up basically everything using Android File Transfer.

The only thing I haven't got to are the text messages and images stored in the Hangouts app. I know I could use something like [this](http://www.pcmobitech.com/backup-android-with-super-backup-app/), bud sadly my phone's screen is completely black.

I can't seem to find them in the filesystem,
[image]
and the `SMSBackupRestore` is from a previous backup.

**Is there a way to get all of the texts and images directly to my mac using Android File Transfer?**

I found online a bunch of links (listed below), but they all seem to require to install a program on the mac (which I most definitively do not want to do):

- http://www.androidphonesoft.com/resources/backup-sms-from-android-to-pc.html
- http://www.android-file-manager.com/resources/transfer-text-messages-from-android-to-computer.html
- https://www.recovery-android.com/transfer-sms-from-android-to-computer.html
- https://www.mobikin.com/android-backup/transfer-text-messages-from-android-to-computer.html
- https://drfone.wondershare.com/message/recover-messages-from-broken-android.html

Comment: Afraid not, as the relevant data are stored in the app's private area you only can access with root powers. With a totally blank screen, `adb backup` is out of the question as you'd have to confirm that on your device's screen.

Comment: @Izzy - Thanks for your reply. Have you ever heard or used any of the recommended programs i listed in the question?

Comment: I'm not a Mac guy; but `recovery-android.com` links often turned up as spam here. Got the same feeling about wondershare, but cannot tell for sure. The others I've not even heard of.

Comment: Unless I am completely off-base here, doesn't using Hangouts for SMS/IM's back that up on Google's end anyways, so if you get a new/replacement device and login to Google/Hangouts, everything should be there already?

Comment: @RMarkwald - I'm not sure, are you suggesting that all the conversations would be loaded automatically by syncing my gmail account to the new device? I know this happens for contacts but not aware of hangouts. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @Matteo I used to have a Nexus 6 on Project Fi, and then switch to a carrier (Verizon) and logged into Google, opened Hangouts, and was able to send/receive texts from that, and the conversations were there (both on phone and via web browser on computer).